# TCP Checksum, why?

Tags: tcpip, checksum

Why does TCP need a checksum, when lower layers do integrity checks anyways (like Ethernet CRC)?

Answer (score 13):

The TCP protocol guarantees accurate delivery regardless of underlying mechanisms.  There is no guarantee that every protocol that it might run over will do any sort of integrity checking.  [SLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol), for example, has no error detection.

Comment: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt

Comment: If you don't need accuracy or guaranteed delivery you can always use UDP.

Comment: @Richard Hoskins why did you link to IP over CP (carrier pigeon)?

Comment: Pigeons are notorious for dropping "packets".  Thanks, I'll be here all week.  Please tip your waitstaff.  Try the veal.

Comment: @quack As an example of protocol that does no error checking.

Comment: i know, i just wanted an excuse to say "IP over CP" :)

Comment: :%s/CP/AC/g^M:%s/carrier pigeon/Avian Carriers/g^M (please excuse my `vi`.)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a protocol that roots in the early 1970s. The Layer Model of communication was not common sense yet back then.

I personally think of it as just that, a relict of the early years of protocol design.

Here is why I think this checksum is nuts:

1. it is too weak to deliver meaningful protection
2. still painful to calculate (especially on microcontrollers. It's a waste of cycles)
3. it does not protect against manipulation (because it's so easy to fix)
4. many implementations ignore it anyway