# Is downloading a media file twice and comparing their hash values enough to verify their integrity?

Tags: file-corruption, hashing, youtube-dl, checksum, data-integrity

I often use youtube-dl to download videos. As far as I know, there is no data integrity verfication built in to youtube-dl, so what I do to verify that a video isn't corrupted in some way after downloading it is to download it twice and check if their md5 values match.

I'm no expert on the ways data corruption might occur, so is it possible that a video or audio file can be corrupted the same way even after downloading twice, resulting in matching md5 values even though both files are corrupt?

Comment: You may want to use a third-party program such as `ffmpeg` to try and verify if the video has any issues. Regardless of when or how corruption occurs, MD5 sums only tell you if the files are the same. A file could (possibly) have issues even before you download it.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I'm aware that a file may be already corrupted on the server side even before downloading. My question is, is it possible for the same corruption to happen during different downloads of the same file, resulting in matching md5 values across files even though they were corrupted during download?

Comment: Simply downloading a file shouldn't result in any corruption unless there is active tampering going on or there is defective hardware in at either end computer. Unintentional data corruption en route should result in packets being transparently retransmitted or the connection failing. If you assume that the data is correct on the server then if the download succeeds and you have data corruption then you probably have faulty RAM or a failing disk.

Comment: Related: [TCP Checksum](https://superuser.com/questions/50585/tcp-checksum-why/50587#50587) and [Getting corrupted data](https://superuser.com/questions/748915/getting-corrupted-data-from-the-internet-shouldnt-tcp-checksums-prevent-this) (possible network hardware bugs causing corruption).

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for the helpful info. My question is specifically if it's possible a file can get corrupted en route the same way every time it's downloaded due to some hardware or software issue on my PC, resulting in matching hash values across those files even though they contain corrupted data.

Comment: Data can [extremely rarely] get corrupted on its way to you. if it does, then fetching it again will probably just fetch a cached copy from the nearest local node [possibly even at your own ISP]. This will be the same corrupted file.  This used to happen more often on http connections, not https. As it happens so rarely, I wouldn't even bother to test for it. If it does happen, rebooting computer & router is usually sufficient to prevent the cached copy being served again [or using a different browser (if applicable) or computer.]